# Create new values using Interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a vector **x=[7 8 8 8...]** and the correspont vector **y=[13 14 15 16...]** , which give me some points , like in the picture below
[image]

Now **I want to create two (or N generally) new points between every couple** of the given  points.I think this should be done using Interpolation, but I have not find something that I can use in this situation.

The result should be something like this :

x= [ 7   **7.4 7.7**  8    **8    8**   8...] ,

y=[ 13 **13.3 13.8** 14 **14.2 14.5** 15...]

Comment: Is linear interpolation sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to use is `interp1`, in this case, for example:

```
N=3;
x=[7 8 8 9];
y=[7 10 15 17];
originalSpacing=1:length(x);
finalSpacing=1:1/N:4; 

xx=interp1(originalSpacing,x,finalSpacing);
yy=interp1(originalSpacing,y,finalSpacing);
```

Will result in the new interpolated series xx and yy

xx = [7 7.3333 7.6667 8 8 8 8 8.3333 8.6667 9]

yy = [7 8 9 10 11.6667 13.3333 15 15.6667 16.3333 17]

Comment: I believe that you mean `xx=interp1(originalSpacing,x,finalSpacing)`.

Comment: Ok. This works. This is a Linear Interpolation. What about a non-linear?

Comment: @AlexandrosMel Look at the interp1 documentation. You can just add a fouth parameter specifying the interpolation method. Either 'spline', 'pchip', or 'cubic' provide non-linear interpolations

Answer (score 1):

Using the `interp` you can increase your data

```
a=1:10;
b=interp(a,3);
b=b(1:end-2);
```

I removed the last 2 points as they are outside of the range, but you can use them if they are of for you.